# Spring JMS start listening to jms queues on request

Tags: java, spring, jms, spring-jms

Spring provides `@JMSListener` annotation to listen to messages from a particular queue. There is also an alternative to [implement `JmsListenerConfigurer`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#jms-annotated-programmatic-registration) and register a `MessageListener`.

In both the cases, the name of the queue has to be known at the time when the application starts, either by hardcoding in the code or via properties.

Is there a way to listen to a queue whose name is known to the application much later after it started?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work.

1. Configure the `@JmsListener` with a dummy queue name and an `id`.
2. Configure the [listener container factory](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jms.html#jms-annotated-support) with `autoStartup` false.
3. When you are ready, get a reference to the listener container using it's `id` from the `JmsListenerEndpointRegistry` (auto wire the registry into your app and call `getListenerContainer(id)`).
4. Cast the container to an `AbstractMessageListenerContainer` and call `setDestinationName` (or `setDestination`) with the desired queue.
5. `start()` it.

Comment: If you wish to dynamically create lots of containers, then just create the containers programmatically, call `afterPropertiesSet()`, then `start()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try this and update. Would you happen to know how heavy the containers are, compared to the listener objects, in case I happen to have multiple on request queue listeners?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean; each `@JmsListener` runs in a `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` created by the factory. It's effectively the same as creating the container programmatically and wrapping your POJO listener in a `MessageListenerAdapter`.

Comment: Ah, thanks for clearing that up. On second thought, I liked the effective way you mentioned in the last comment and ended up creating a container when I have the queue name and then init and start it. It also allows me to attach a message listener, instead of trying to route the message from the `@JMSListener`  which is neat too.

Comment: Thanks Gary! Above solution helped me create ContainerFactory and Listeners dynamically.